# function instance hasOwnProperty() confusion

Tags: javascript

Since the `doOtherStuff` function is defined directly on the `b` instance, and not "above" it in the prototype chain (like on `base` or even `Object`), why does `b.hasOwnProperty('doOtherStuff')` return false?

```
var base = (function () {

    var cls = function () { };

    cls.prototype.doStuff = function () {
        console.log('dostuff');
    };

    return cls;

})();

var child = (function () {

    var cls = function () {
        base.call(this);
    };

    cls.prototype = Object.create(base.prototype);
    cls.prototype.constructor = child;

    cls.prototype.doOtherStuff = function () { // <--
        console.log('doOtherStuff');
    }

    return cls;

})();

var b = new child();

console.log(b.hasOwnProperty('doOtherStuff'), 'doOtherStuff' in b); //false true
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5FzBQ/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Since the `doOtherStuff` function is defined directly on the `b` instance

That's not true; you defined that property in `cls.prototype`.

`hasOwnProperty()` will only return true if you write `this.property = ...` (or `b.property`).

Comment: Ooooh, so as long as the function is on the prototype, you can't tell what "level" it's on?

Comment: @Johan: You can loop through `Object.getPrototypeOf()` until you find a prototype that has it.

Comment: Not when I'm on IE7/8 which I need to support :/ But whatever, you taught me what I needed to know in my question, thanks for that!

Comment: @Johan: Then you can use `__proto__`

Answer (score 1):

`doOtherStuff` is not defined directly on `b`, `b` inherits `doOtherStuff` from its prototype. `hasOwnProperty` distinguishes between properties defined directly on the object versus properties inherited from the prototype whereas `in` does not.

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty

Comment: Gotcha. So what would be more suitable here do check if I want to know if a certain "type" (base/child) etc. has a certain function? `typeof b.doOtherStuff === 'function'`?

Comment: Yes, that would work fine regardless of where `doOtherStuff` came from (prototype versus defined directly on `b`). If `doOtherStuff` didn't exist on `b` the result of `typeof b.doOtherStuff` would be `'undefined'`.